# How can I create a webpage with a graph output from an input?

Tags: javascript, r, input, graph

I need to create a graph based on a user's input. However, I don't want to do a flash or java type of thing, where the graph appears in the same window (I would like for it to send to another page instead of showing results on the same page)

An example of what I am looking for is the [COILS Server](http://embnet.vital-it.ch/software/COILS_form.html). If you type in a sequence that is a coiled coil, you get the following graph.
[image: graph]

Mine would need to be a scatterplot and linear regression graph. I've looked through the source code, and this is the portion where I think the graph is coming from.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16617489-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'ch.embnet.org', '.ch.embnet.org', 'embnet.vital-it.ch']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.srcww') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

I can't understand this script however and how to make it into a graph. Most of my programming is in R, so the best case scenario would be if I could just plug it into an R compiler and output the graph. But if that is not possible/feasible, what is another way I could go about doing this? Any resources would be appreciated. I've seen some charting libraries but I can't have a logo or anything on it (I can pay for it however if that's the only thing I need to do)

Thanks.

Comment: maybe shiny could help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply serve PNG files generated by R (via `png()` or `CairoPNG()`) on any webserver - you just write the file in the corresponding directory and you're done. YOu don't need any JavaScript or anything like that.

If you want dynamic plot generation, you can use [FastRWeb](http://rforge.net/FastRWeb) which serves R scripts directly so your code would be simply an R script like

```
run <- function(...) {
   WebPlot(800, 600)
   ## plot here...
   out(p)
   done()
}
```